# how to position elements next to each other in a div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position the elements next to each other. but the third field keeps appearing in a separate row.

```html
<div class="row">
  <label>
    <input name="select_source" id="select-source-radio-btn" type="radio"/>
    <span style="font-size: medium;font-weight: bold;  margin: 5px;">SELECT A SOURCE</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input name="select_source"  id="select-group-radio-btn" type="radio"/>
    <span style="font-size: medium ;font-weight: bold;">SELECT A GROUP</span>
  </label>
  <div class="input-field">
    <input id="email" type="email" class="validate" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i position the two radio buttons and email field next to each other?  i tried adding float:left and float:right to the second element.

Comment: Which Bootstrap Version are you using?

Answer (score 4):

I think that using **flexbox** is a much better approach to organize elements like this.
It's mostly supported, not buggy as floats and easy to use.

```css
.disp {
  display: flex;
justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<div class="row disp">
  <label>
    <input name="select_source" id="select-source-radio-btn" type="radio"/>
    <span style="font-size: medium;font-weight: bold;  margin: 5px;">SELECT A SOURCE</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input name="select_source"  id="select-group-radio-btn" type="radio"/>
    <span style="font-size: medium ;font-weight: bold;">SELECT A GROUP</span>
  </label>
  <div class="input-field disp">
    <input id="email" type="email" class="validate" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works best since it looks same across all browsers. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add display block to both divs like this:

```css
.disp {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row disp">
  <label>
    <input name="select_source" id="select-source-radio-btn" type="radio"/>
    <span style="font-size: medium;font-weight: bold;  margin: 5px;">SELECT A SOURCE</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input name="select_source"  id="select-group-radio-btn" type="radio"/>
    <span style="font-size: medium ;font-weight: bold;">SELECT A GROUP</span>
  </label>
  <div class="input-field disp">
    <input id="email" type="email" class="validate" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: adding a <div class="col"> to the elements also works.

Answer (score 0):

you can do 
    display:inline-block or float:left after the first div

Answer (score 0):

you can use css on the div if you want as well

```css
    div {
      display:inline-block;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="row">
  <label>
    <input name="select_source" id="select-source-radio-btn" type="radio"/>
    <span style="font-size: medium;font-weight: bold;  margin: 5px;">SELECT A     SOURCE</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input name="select_source"  id="select-group-radio-btn" type="radio"/>
    <span style="font-size: medium ;font-weight: bold;">SELECT A GROUP</span>
  </label>
  <div class="input-field">
    <input id="email" type="email" class="validate" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna do CSS for the same try doing:

```
<div class="row">
  <label>
    <input name="select_source" id="select-source-radio-btn" type="radio"/>
    <span style="font-size: medium;font-weight: bold;  margin: 5px;">SELECT A SOURCE</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input name="select_source"  id="select-group-radio-btn" type="radio"/>
    <span style="font-size: medium ;font-weight: bold;">SELECT A GROUP</span>
  </label>
  <span class="input-field">
    <input id="email" type="email" class="validate" placeholder="Email">
  </span>
</div>
```

You shall get the desired results